# CSS going insane

Tags: css

I'm having issues with my media queries, for some reason.

Here is what my CSS looks like

```css
#main {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Using PHP, I give a class to my HTML for each browser in case of hacks, namely for IE, like so:

```php
<?php
   // ----| user agent (browser) |----------------------------
      $msie = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'MSIE') ? true : false;
      $firefox = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Firefox') ? true : false;
      $safari = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Safari') ? true : false;
      $chrome = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Chrome') ? true : false;
?>
<html class="<?php if($msie == true){ echo "msie "; } if($firefox == true){ echo "firefox "; } if($safari == true){ echo "safari "; } if($chrome == true){ echo "chrome "; } ?>" lang="fr">
```

The problem is, for my CSS to work, I need to call the html class, like so:

```css
.firefox #main,
.chrome #main,
.safari #main,
.msie #main {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Any ideas as to why this would be happening?

Comment: Why don't you set the class (and CSS) for the `<body>` element instead?

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see a media query here.

Comment: Ideas as to **why what** would be happening?

Comment: Warning: User Agent string detection is dangerous. Point in case: IE11 will fail your test as it no longer includes "MSIE" in its UA string.

Comment: FYI - not that you should even do user agent sniffing like that, but I'm afraid it's flawed as per safari and chrome in particular. `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36` Note it contains "Chrome" *and* "Safari"

Comment: Also, ($variable == true) is redundant, and just makes code more laborious to read. There could be other ways to simplify your code as well.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the MQ. However, changing the classes onto the body somehow solved the problem in every browser. Wierd...

Comment: Also, what's the point in detecting IE, but not detecting the version? Your code is going to see IE10 as being the same thing as IE6. Again, I recommend not doing browser detection of this type at all, but if you are going to do it, at least make it worthwhile doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note**: User agent detection is a bit different from "media queries".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Another observation: I think, you intend to add those CSS classes to the "body" tag, not the "html" tag.

In regards to your question about IE hacks, below is a great resource on "How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet"
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Moving the class to the BODY rather than the HTML tag somehow did the trick. I've never had this problem before, which is why I've asked.

As for detecting IE versions, I do have if IE 7 and if IE 8 classes. IE9 and up have never been issues.

Finally, the UA is used and so are MQ's. I've just messed them up, for some wierd reason. TGIF, I guess.

Comment: As a side note, your example selector should be lighter.
Simply: 
`#main {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}` should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this library in the past and it is great (and being actively maintained):

https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Your css has issues you should not need to use #main more than once in it also as mentioned before the html should be a  tag

try this

```html
<body class="<?php if($msie == true){ echo "msie "; } if($firefox == true){ echo "firefox "; } if($safari == true){ echo "safari "; } if($chrome == true){ echo "chrome "; } ?>" lang="fr">
```

CSS

```css
.firefox,
.chrome,
.safari,
.msie, 
#main {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```